# How to save user input from Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I'm building an app that is supposed to take text entered from the user and place them into the textviews in a custom list item.  The user enters the text into an `AlertDialog` but once the `AlertDialog` closes (hence destroyed), all the text entered is destroyed alongside with it and gives me a `NullPointerException` error.

**This is code that handles the Dialog creation and data retrieving:**

```
    public class AssignmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_assignment);

        ...

        FloatingActionButton assignmentAddButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.assignment_add_button);

        assignmentAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editCourseInfoDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    private void editCourseInfoDialog() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(AssignmentActivity.this);
        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assignment_edit_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AssignmentActivity.this);
        dialog.setView(dialogLayout);

        final TextView name = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.assignmentNameView);
        final TextView mark = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.assignmentMarkView);
        final TextView overallMark = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.assignmentOverallMarkView);
        final TextView weight = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.assignmentWeightView);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                assignment.setName(String.valueOf(name.getText()));
                assignment.setMark(Double.valueOf(mark.getText() + ""));
                assignment.setMarkOutOf(Double.valueOf(overallMark.getText() + ""));
                assignment.setPercentage(Double.valueOf(weight.getText() + ""));
                assignmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using the values in the same class then just create a global variable for that class and store TextView inputs. If you are using values in different class save inputs in SharedPreference.

Comment: The TextViews are hooked into the custom AlertDialog xml file.  Not the `activity_assignment.xml` of the `AssignmentActivity.java` file

Comment: You know it's too much code for the small problem. Better just post relevant codes.

Comment: I post them just in case.  Often times when I ask questions, another user wants to see the entire java file.

Comment: If you are getting NPE then post your logcat.

Comment: Check my answer and though it will remove the above exception it might cause new ones as your adapter is not initialized and you are not updating your adapter correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your initialization.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(AssignmentActivity.this);
View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assignment_edit_dialog, null);
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AssignmentActivity.this);
dialog.setView(dialogLayout);

final TextView name = (TextView) dialogLayout .findViewById(R.id.assignmentNameView);
final TextView mark = (TextView) dialogLayout .findViewById(R.id.assignmentMarkView);
final TextView overallMark = (TextView) dialogLayout .findViewById(R.id.assignmentOverallMarkView);
final TextView weight = (TextView) dialogLayout .findViewById(R.id.assignmentWeightView);
```

As you said TextViews are hooked up with AlertDialog custom view then they view context should be of Dialog view.

You have a lot to learn in terms of concept. You are setting adapter before initializing your list.

```
assignmentAdapter = new AssignmentListAdapter(assignmentList, this); // at this line **assignmentList** is null as you initiliaze after this line
assignment = new Assignment(this);
```

You must initialize first like this

```
assignment = new Assignment(this);
assignmentAdapter = new AssignmentListAdapter(assignmentList, this);
```

Comment: Adding dialog turns `.findViewById` to red.

Comment: It must be showing some error. If you click onto that then you can find it.

Comment: Error.  Check the new LogCat.

Comment: Of course, that will be an error. If haven't initialized your `assignment` object.

Comment: And you have other uninitialized Objects as well, so they will also throw Exception.

Comment: I took all of them in mind and edited them.  All the code above are updated.  I'm getting an error regarding my List size in the adapter even though the list is initialized.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because it did help clean up my code.  If you think that my question was well asked, can you also give me an upvote?